# Gnuplot error on command "set data s l"

Tags: gnuplot

My program has gnuplot script and its first line is

```
set data s l
```

But this makes error

```
"cdia.GNUBAND", line 1: unrecognized option - see 'help set'.
```

I think it's the version problem and I have to change the "set data s l" command in right way. I searched on web but couldn't find it.. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is the shortcut for `set data style lines`, which is deprecated since version 4.0 (released in 2004). To replace this line, use

```
set style data lines
```

This sets the default plotting style for data set to `lines`, i.e. the commands

```
set style data lines
plot 'data.dat'
```

and

```
plot 'data.dat' with lines
```

are equivalent.